# Extract database from mssql from windows machine,any tools available?

Tags: php, sql-server, database

i am planning to extract/export data from mssql server and import it into mysql,i googled for last 4 hours looking for mssql client but no success.the server running SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express.

Comment: What version of SQL server is it? The MSSQL client is called SQL Management Studio. Worst case scenario just download SQL Express 2008 and you will get management studio with it. Then you can connect and there is an import/export data wizard. Though to be honest, I'd just connect to the MSSQL server via ODBC from MySql and transfer the data (though there are some issues when converting from different types that the driver might have trouble with)

Comment: its SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express

Answer (score 0):

There's an Export Data wizard in SSMS, it can connect to mysql db (via ODBC) and export the data.